# Google MAPs API / Javascript / Search box function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm attempting to embed a search box functionality by calling on the google maps api which draws data from google fusion table. The search box should search for the Name of markers on the map. But when I enter any character within the box, the search fails.  I'm not sure why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport"></meta>
    <title>Merge of Vino_Brew_BBQ and Markers - Google Fusion Tables</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, #googft-mapCanvas {
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAI_3RMI43f45RgHC9MLdZbePINAqH_ZM0"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var VinoBrewBBQLayer;
    var VinoBrewBBQTable = '15qpgfFdsMTpuwQ_gR2-LgBSlN6Z7EPhCegikJ0xy';
    var VinoBrewBBQColumn = 'Geometry';


    function initialize() {
        google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
        var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
                (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
        if (isMobile) {
            var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
            viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
        }
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
        mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '500px';
        mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.340072697821267, -98.913833984375),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

        VinoBrewBBQLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            map: map,
            heatmap: { enabled: false },
            query: {
                select: VinoBrewBBQColumn,
                from: VinoBrewBBQTable,
                where: ""
            },
            options: {
                styleId: 2,
                templateId: 2
            }
        });

        if (isMobile) {
            var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
            var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
            var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
            legend.style.display = 'none';
            legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
            legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
            legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
                legend.style.display = 'block';
                legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
            }
            legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
                legend.style.display = 'none';
                legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    }

    function SearchLayer(VinoBrewBBQLayer, VinoBrewBBQTable, map){
        var store = document.getElementById('StoreTextInput').value;
        var search = "NAME CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + store + "'";

            if(!VinoBrewBBQLayer.getMap()){
                VinoBrewBBQLayer.setMap(map);
                alert (search);
            }
            VinoBrewBBQLayer.setOptions({
                query:  {
                    select: VinoBrewBBQColumn,
                    from: VinoBrewBBQTable,
                    where: search
                },
                options: {
                    styleId: 3,
                    templateId: 3
                }
            });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Search for

Comment: What do you mean by "the search fails"?  When I run your code, it doesn't fail, it works, but all the markers turn red.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `search` string.  The column names in FusionTables are case sensitive.  "NAME" should be "Name":

```
var search = "NAME CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + store + "'";
```

should be:

```
var search = "Name CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + store + "'";
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d1gbq87/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var VinoBrewBBQLayer;
var VinoBrewBBQTable = '15qpgfFdsMTpuwQ_gR2-LgBSlN6Z7EPhCegikJ0xy';
var VinoBrewBBQColumn = 'Geometry';


function initialize() {
  google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
  var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
    (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
  if (isMobile) {
    var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
    viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
  }
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
  mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '500px';
  mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.340072697821267, -98.913833984375),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend-open'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('googft-legend'));

  VinoBrewBBQLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: VinoBrewBBQColumn,
      from: VinoBrewBBQTable,
      where: ""
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });

  if (isMobile) {
    var legend = document.getElementById('googft-legend');
    var legendOpenButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-open');
    var legendCloseButton = document.getElementById('googft-legend-close');
    legend.style.display = 'none';
    legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
    legendCloseButton.style.display = 'block';
    legendOpenButton.onclick = function() {
      legend.style.display = 'block';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
    legendCloseButton.onclick = function() {
      legend.style.display = 'none';
      legendOpenButton.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function(evt) {
    SearchLayer(VinoBrewBBQLayer, VinoBrewBBQTable, map);
  })
}

function SearchLayer(VinoBrewBBQLayer, VinoBrewBBQTable, map) {
  var store = document.getElementById('StoreTextInput').value;
  var search = "Name CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + store + "'";

  if (!VinoBrewBBQLayer.getMap()) {
    VinoBrewBBQLayer.setMap(map);
    alert(search);
  }
  console.log("select:" + VinoBrewBBQColumn + "\nfrom:" + VinoBrewBBQTable + "\nwhere:" + search);
  VinoBrewBBQLayer.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: VinoBrewBBQColumn,
      from: VinoBrewBBQTable,
      where: search
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 3,
      templateId: 3
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googft-mapCanvas {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="StoreTextInput" value="City Market" />
<input id="btn" value="search" type="button" />
<div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
<div id="googft-legend-open"></div>
```